# inserting multiline string as a variable in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to insert, via RJS a multiline string taken from a textarea. Doing:

```
$('#description').text('<%= simple_format description %>');
```

does not work because it will generate something like this:

```
$('#description').text('<p>first line
<br />second line</p>

<p>fourth line</p>');
```

Because the string isnt on a single line, the JS call fails. So now that simple_format formatted the string correctly, how can I have it all print on a single line in my RJS file?

Comment: You need to JS-escape the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#description').text('<%= simple_format(description).gsub("\n", "\\n").gsub("\r", "\\r").gsub("\t", "\\t").gsub("'","\\'")  %>');
```

This replaces the newline character with an escape sequence Javascript understands.  Similarly for other characters like carriage-return and tab.  Moreover it replaces the ' character which is a string delimiter character with an escape sequence for it so that a string such as "It's mine" does not cause any surprises.

Comment: almost perfect, should have been simple_format(description).gsub("\n", "\\n").gsub("'","\\'")

Comment: @Alain: Thanks :-)  I accidentally answered the question thinking this was an ASP.NET question and noticed the ruby-on-rails tag a few minutes later!!! During the past few minutes tried to learn enough Ruby to make it appropriate for the question, but ... Thanks :-) I will edit accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

You could (preferably) use the built in `escape_javascript()` or `j()` methods:

```
$('#description').text('<%= j(simple_format(description)) %>');
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript