# select_tag and javascript in rails issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to generate html using rails select_tag and save it into a variable to be dynamically used.
For some reason, below is causes this error:

Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Below is the problem code:

```
function addItemRowHTML(offsetidentifiervalue)
{
    $node = ' \
         <%= select_tag "currency",  
            options_for_select(Country.all.each_with_index.map {
            |country, index| 
                [country["currency_code"],
                 country["currency_code"]]},
                @invoice["data"]["currency"] ),
                :style => "width:120px"
        %> \
        ';

}
```

text_field_tag works though

```
$node =' <%= text_field_tag("amount", "10") %> ';
```

so how would i handle select_tag ? thanks

Comment: here are some of my failed example attempts: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9615678

Comment: check the generated javascript - it will likely have unescaped single quotes in it, therefore be invalid syntax.

Comment: you are right but its not unescaped single quotes, its probably unescaped multiline from the options generated https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9616215

Comment: then it probably needs reformatting to insert \ on unescaped multiline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% html_select_tag = select_tag( "currency",  
      options_for_select(Country.all.map(&:currency_code),
      @invoice["data"]["currency"] ),
      :style => "width:120px" ).gsub("\n", "\\n").gsub("'","\\'") %>

var $node = '<%= html_select_tag %>';
```

Someone already answered similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631186/2134720

Comment: i dont think that works. previous works... im not sure if you can assign html_select_tag, atleast that didnt work

Comment: Supposed to work. Tested it.
What kind of error did it raise for you?

Comment: _form.html.erb:320: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting ')' options_for_select(Country.all.map(&:currency_code)}, ^

Comment: oops the curly brace close is not supposed to be there.
Updated the answer. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: actually it does work with html_select_tag variable... but with the code below. do you want me to reedit the code from below, and i'll mark it as answered ? I'll just mark it right anyway, all depends probably how you want it, main thing is gsub replacement code. thats what is important.

Comment: Yep you can edit.
Would definitely want to knw, why it doesn't works for you.
Also interesting you accessing the object like a hash -> `country["currency_code"]` and not `country.currency_code`. Are you using mongo?

Comment: no im using json. so somewhat mongo like but on postgress

Comment: oww..
So this shorthand `Country.all.map(&:currency_code)` wont work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
    $node = '<% select_tag("currency",  
            options_for_select(Country.all.each_with_index.map {
            |country, index| 
                [country["currency_code"],
                 country["currency_code"]]},
                @invoice["data"]["currency"] ),
                :style => "width:120px").gsub("\n", "\\n").gsub("'","\\'")
    %> ';
```

and this would be a better solution, there are less newlines to escape using raw

```
    $node = '<% raw select_tag("currency",  
            options_for_select(Country.all.each_with_index.map {
            |country, index| 
                [country["currency_code"],
                 country["currency_code"]]},
                @invoice["data"]["currency"] ),
                :style => "width:120px").gsub("\n", "\\n").gsub("'","\\'")
    %> ';
```